# Postgresql 9.4 Alter Column Text to Boolean with Values

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "TestResults" (
"Id"                text PRIMARY KEY,
"Name"              text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
"Result"            text CHECK ("Comment" IN ('Pass', 'Fail')),
"CreatedBy"         text NOT NULL,
"CreatedOn"         timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
);
```

We are using PostgreSQL 9.4

The user is currently able to select either `Pass` or `Fail` from a drop down menu, and we have been storing those strings in the database in the `Result` column. We would like to change that to a boolean value.

How can I change the `Result` column from text to boolean while keeping the values the users have already entered?

Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any time you want to change a column's type but there is no default conversion from the old values to the new ones, you want to use a [USING clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) to specify how to convert the old values to the new ones:

> The optional `USING` clause specifies how to compute the new column value from the old; if omitted, the default conversion is the same as an assignment cast from old data type to new. A `USING` clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type.

So first get rid of the CHECK constraint, you can find the name by doing a `\d "TestResults"` from `psql` but it is probably `"TestResults_Result_check"`:

```
alter table "TestResults" drop constraint "TestResults_Result_check";
```

Then an ALTER COLUMN (with a USING clause) to change the type:

```
alter table "TestResults"
alter column "Result"
set data type boolean
using case
    when "Result" = 'Pass' then true
    when "Result" = 'Fail' then false
    else null
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. I was having trouble finding information on how to use the `case` statement. The documentation is overall pretty wonderful for postgreSQL but I found it lacking in that area.